# Plotly Multicategory X Axis Ordering

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to create a multi category x axis with dates, the below code & graph gives me what I want it terms of how it looks but it's just out of order. I've tried using the 'Original x-axis' column instead of month but then the format doesn't appear correctly and I can't seem to change the format of it.

```
import random
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({"Year":np.repeat([2018,2019],[8,12]), 
              "Month": ["May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr","May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
             "Original x-axis": pd.date_range(start = "2018-05-01", end = "2019-12-01", freq = "MS"),
             "Customer Satisfaction Score": random.sample(range(30,100), 20)})


fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
                        #x = cust["Original x-axis"], 
                        x = [df["Year"],df["Month"]],
                      y = df["Customer Satisfaction Score"], mode = "lines"))

fig.update_layout(plot_bgcolor = "white",
                 annotations = [dict(text = "Customer Satisfaction Score",
                                    yref = "paper",
                                    xref = "paper",
                                    x = 0,
                                    y = 1.1,
                                     font = dict(size = 16, color = "#909497"),
                                    showarrow = False)],
                 font = dict(size = 12, color = "#BDC3C7"))
                 #xaxis = dict(tickformat = "%b"))

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: So how you want your x-axis to be? Can you please elaborate about your required xaxis like what format?

Comment: Basically the same format it's in on the graph already but just in order, 2019 starts at May and Jan to Apr are at the end of 2019

Answer (score 1):

Please check the snippet. You need to sort your date_time column based on **year** as well as **month**.

Here I created an extra column for that. Rest all the part is same.

```
df['month'] = df['Original x-axis'].dt.strftime('%b-%Y')
```

[image: PLOT]

```
import random
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
df = pd.DataFrame({"Year":np.repeat([2018,2019],[8,12]), 
              "Month": ["May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr","May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
             "Original x-axis": pd.date_range(start = "2018-05-01", end = "2019-12-01", freq = "MS"),
             "Customer Satisfaction Score": random.sample(range(30,100), 20)})

df['month'] = df['Original x-axis'].dt.strftime('%b-%Y')
fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
                        #x = cust["Original x-axis"], 
                        x = [df["Year"],df["month"]],
                      y = df["Customer Satisfaction Score"], mode = "lines"))

fig.update_layout(plot_bgcolor = "white",
                 annotations = [dict(text = "Customer Satisfaction Score",
                                    yref = "paper",
                                    xref = "paper",
                                    x = 0,
                                    y = 1.1,
                                     font = dict(size = 16, color = "#909497"),
                                    showarrow = False)],
                 font = dict(size = 12, color = "#BDC3C7"))
                 #xaxis = dict(tickformat = "%b"))

fig.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I'm trying to remove the unnecessary repetition of the year, so I only want 2018 to appear once for May to Dec on the left hand side of the graph and 2019 to appear once for Jan to Dec on the right hand side of the graph.

Comment: @FluffySheep1990 Sorry according to my knowledge that wont be possible because you dont have Jan to Apr in your 2018 column. Either you can **sort your column by year** but in that case 2019 will come first and 2018 will go afterwards and your graph will change slightly but your format will remain same. OR you can programatically add Jan to Apr in 2018 based on datetime condition and Map your **Customer Satisfaction Score** to **NaN**  from Jan to Apr 2018. This will also work and your format will remain same just you will be having some empty spaces in beginning due to NaN.